# How to replace non-ASCII characters in a string in PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex

I need to replace characters in a string which are not represented with a single byte.

My string is like this

```
$inputText="centralkøkkenet kliniske diætister";
```

In that string there are characters like **ø** and **æ**. These characters should be replaced. How do I mention these in a regular expression that I can use for replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace everything other than alphanumeric and space character then try it.

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yU4iI7/2)

Sample code:

```
$re = "/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/";
$str = "centralkøkkenet kliniske diætister";
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

---

Better use `[^\w\s]` or `[\W\S]` to make it short and simple as suggested by @hjpotter92 as well in comments.

Pattern explanation:

```
[^\w\s]                any character except: word characters:
                        (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _), whitespace (\n, \r, \t,\f, and " ")

[\W\S]                 any character of: 
                         non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _), 
                         non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
```

Comment: `\w` includes underscore as well. It's correct also

Comment: i am unable to get the result. i used like this `$resultText = preg_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', '', $inputText);`. Is it correct?

Comment: Thanks.Its working. but it removing space which is in string. I dont want to remove spaces.I am getting output like this **centralkkkenetkliniskeditister**.

Comment: I don't think so. I have added space in the regex pattern. Look in the pattern there is a space after `0-9` or use `/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]`

Comment: Thanks. working fine.you didnt mention `\s` in the given code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep also punctation ie.: `-'"!`..., use this one:

```
$text = 'central-køkkenet "kliniske" diætister!';
$new = preg_replace('/[\x7F-\xFF]/ui', '', $text);
echo $new,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
central-kkkenet "kliniske" ditister!
```