# str_ireplace works as str_replace

Tags: php, string, local

I need to replace all local characters (including upper case) with small ascii characters in a url string.

```
$str = "č-ć-đ-š-ž-Č-Ć-Đ-Š-Ž";
echo str_ireplace(array('č', 'ć', 'đ', 'š', 'ž'), array('c', 'c', 'd', 's', 'z'), $str);
```

result - `c-c-d-s-z-Č-Ć-Đ-Š-Ž`
I expected - `c-c-d-s-z-c-c-d-s-z`

How to get expected result using `str_ireplace()` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace non-ASCII characters in a string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25236761/how-to-replace-non-ascii-characters-in-a-string-in-php)

Comment: @Marten, it's not duplicated. My question is specifically about `str_ireplace` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the PHP [string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) handle the strings as sequences of bytes, i.e. single-byte characters (`ASCII`).

You want to replace characters in a string that contains multi-byte characters.
[`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) (kind of) works because it doesn't care to interpret the strings as characters. It replaces a sequence of bytes with another sequence of bytes and that's all. Most of the times it will not break anything while working with `ASCII` or even `UTF-8` encoded strings (because the way `UTF-8` was designed). However, it can produce unexpected results with other encodings.

When asked to handle characters outside the `ASCII` range, [`str_ireplace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) works the same as`str_replace()`. It's "case insensitive" functionality requires splitting the strings into chars and recognizing the lowercase-uppercase pairs. But since it doesn't handle multi-byte characters it cannot recognize any character whose code is greater than 127.

For multi-byte character strings you should use the functions provided by the [Multibyte String](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) PHP extension.

The only function it provides for strings replacement is [`mb_ereg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php) (with the case-insensitive version [`mb_eregi_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-eregi-replace.php)) but they don't help you very much (because they don't work with arrays).

If the list of characters you want to replace is fixed, my suggestion is to use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) with a list of characters that includes both cases:

```
$str = "č-ć-đ-š-ž-Č-Ć-Đ-Š-Ž";
echo str_replace(
         array('č', 'ć', 'đ', 'š', 'ž', 'Č', 'Ć', 'Đ', 'Š', 'Ž'), 
         array('c', 'c', 'd', 's', 'z', 'c', 'c', 'd', 's', 'z'),
         $str
     );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trans them to lower case first,

```
$str = "č-ć-đ-š-ž-Č-Ć-Đ-Š-Ž";
echo str_ireplace(array('č', 'ć', 'đ', 'š', 'ž'), array('c', 'c', 'd', 's', 'z'), mb_strtolower($str, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: This solution solves the problem at hand but has side effects: it lowercases the entire string and maybe this is not desired. (Most probably it is desired, but this is not explicitly stated in the question).

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up uppercase and lowercase characters. `Č` has a different Unicode than `č`, so they are not the same.

Try the following:

```
<?php
    $str = "č-ć-đ-š-ž-Č-Ć-Đ-Š-Ž";
    echo str_ireplace(array('č', 'ć', 'đ', 'š', 'ž', 'Č', 'Ć', 'Đ', 'Š', 'Ž'), array('c', 'c', 'd', 's', 'z', 'c', 'c', 'd', 's', 'z' ), $str);
?>
```

Comment: *"`Č` has a different ASCII code than `č`, so they are not the same"* -- of course they have different codes and they are not the same (but they don't belong to the ASCII code). That's the whole point of `str_ireplace()`, to find and replace both characters, but it fails for a complete different reason.

Comment: Indeed correct, I should be Unicode Character instead of ASCII.